# microsoft 3rd party authentication live.com instead of microsoftonline.com

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0

Trying to implement 3rd party authentication in ASP.net.
we follow example:
[microsoft Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Problem is when we redirect to microsoft for sign in we are sent to **live.com** not **microsoftonline.com**. The message from live.com is "account does not exist..."

live.com will accept personal Microsoft account like myname@oulook.com but not office 365 domain based email like my myname@mycompany.com
yet myname@mycompany.com log in perfectly on microsoftonline.com

I cannot find any where this could be set. I know this is possible as I have seen redirection to microsoftonline.com

I use a private windows to make sure it was not a cookie problem.

any help appreciated.

EDIT: It looks like it is a OAuth2 V1 vs V2 issue.
however it is not clear how to force V2

Answer (score 0):

Yes it was indeed a V2 problem, updated everything to DLL 4.0 and it works microsoftonline.com every time.